# Proof by induction for $n\in\mathbb N$

Tags: calculus, induction, solution-verification

I need some help with the following proof by induction problem:

Prove that for all natural numbers $n\in\Bbb N$:

$$\dfrac{4^{n}}{n + 1} < \dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^{2}}$$

first I proof this first for $n=2$, and we got this
$\dfrac{4^{2}}{2 + 1} < \dfrac{(2 \times 2)!}{(2!)^{2}}$ and this meets inequality.

now for $n=k$  $$\dfrac{4^{k}}{k + 1} < \dfrac{(2k)!}{(k!)^{2}}$$ and if this is true so $$\dfrac{4^{k}}{k + 1} +(k+1) < \dfrac{(2k)!}{(k!)^{2}} +(k+1)$$

After that I don't know how follow this problem. Any help would be sincerely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Note that in your inductive step you've simply written the exact same inequality, except you've added $k+1$ to both sides. That is, you're just adding the same thing to both sides, so the inequality you've written is *equivalent* to the assumption that the inequality holds for $n = k$. What you need to do is show that if it holds for $n=k$, then it must hold for $n=k+1$. It's the domino effect. If one goes, the next one goes. So: the trick is to substitute $n=k+1$ into the original inequality and show that it must be true only if the $n=k$ inequality is true.

Comment: You misunderstood him. What he was trying to obtain the condition for $n=k+1$ by adding $k+1$ to the hypothesis for $n=k$. This is a common step in proving linear series or inequalities by induction.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to show is that if the inequality holds for $n=k$, it also holds for $n = k+1$, i.e.
$$
\frac{4^k}{k+1}< \frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}\Rightarrow \frac{4^{k+1}}{k+2}< \frac{(2k+2)!}{((k+1)!)^2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(n)$ be the given statement.
$$P(n):\ \frac{4n}{n+1}<\frac{2n!}{n!^2}$$
For the base case $n=2$,
$$P(1):\ \frac 8 3 < 6$$
which is true.

Assume $P(k)$ is true for some $\mathbb{N}\ni k\geq 2$.
$$\therefore \frac{4k}{k+1}<\frac{2k!}{k!^2}\quad (*)$$
Now, we wish to prove that $P(k+1)$ is also true.
Note that
$$\frac{2(k+1)!}{(k+1)!^2} = \frac{(2k+2)(2k+1)}{(k+1)^2}\cdot \frac{2k!}{k!^2}$$
By using $(*)$, we get
$$\frac{2(k+1)!}{(k+1)!^2}>\frac{2(2k+1)}{k+1}\cdot \frac{4k}{k+1}$$
$$\implies\frac{2(k+1)!}{(k+1)!^2}>\frac{16k^2+8k}{k^2+2k+1}\quad (**)$$
Now, note that $16k^2\geq 4$ and $8k>4k$ for all $\mathbb{N}\ni k\geq 2$.
$$16k^2+8k>4k+4\quad (1)$$
Similarly, we have
$$k^2+2k+1>4k+4\quad (2)$$
Using $(1)$ and $(2)$ in $(**)$, we get
$$\frac{2(k+1)!}{(k+1)!^2}>\frac{4(k+1)}{(k+1)+1}$$
Thus, we have established that $P(k+1)$ is true whenever $P(k)$ is true.

Hence, by the principle of mathematical induction, we conclude that $P(n)$ is true for all $\mathbb{N}\ni n\geq 2$.

Hope this helps :)